# How to use the communities module "python-louvain" in networkx 2.2?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I used to use this module like this:

```
import community

if __name__ == '__main__':

    G = nx.karate_club_graph()
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

    partition = community.best_partition(G)
```

I installed the correct module:

```
sudo pip3 install python-louvain
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'community' has no attribute 'best_partition'
```

As far as I know it follows the documentation presented [here](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/python-louvain/latest/python-louvain.pdf).

Answer (score 12):

It seems some others have run into this problem before, see:
https://bitbucket.org/taynaud/python-louvain/issues/23/module-has-no-attribute-best_partition

If you have another library called community installed that may be causing a problem. Here is one solution proposed in the thread I linked to:

```
from community import community_louvain
partition = community_louvain.best_partition(G)
```

Comment: This answer works for me!

Answer (score 5):

I am a beginner in using Networkx as well but I used following syntax in Jupyter notebook and it worked fine for me.

```
!pip install python-louvain
from community import community_louvain
communities =community_louvain.best_partition(G)
```

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 2):

You need the package named `python-louvain` from [here](https://github.com/taynaud/python-louvain).

```
!pip install python-louvain

import networkx as nx
import community
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

W = np.random.rand(15,15)
np.fill_diagonal(W,0.0)

G = nx.from_numpy_array(W)
louvain_partition = community.best_partition(G, weight='weight')
modularity2 = community.modularity(louvain_partition, G, weight='weight')
print("The modularity Q based on networkx is {}".format(modularity2))
```

The modularity Q based on networkx is 0.0849022950503318

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why the following situation exists, but there appears to be another package called "community" that does not contain the function "community.best_partition". As stated above, you want the "python-louvain" package, which appears to include a "community" part?! In PyCharm 2020.3, under Preferences -> Project: Python Interpreter, I deleted the "community" package and added the "python-louvain" package. After that, "import community" still worked as did "community.best_partition".

Answer (score 1):

you should install the package below. i use it and it works.
i install it in windows.
https://pypi.org/project/python-louvain/

write "pip install python-louvain" in cmd and after that write program like this:

```
import community
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(30, 0.05)
partition = community.best_partition(G)
size = float(len(set(partition.values())))
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
count = 0
for com in set(partition.values()) :
    count = count + 1
    list_nodes = [nodes for nodes in partition.keys()if partition[nodes] == com]
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, list_nodes, node_size = 20,node_color = str(count / size))

nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

i use python 3.7

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth: I had to

> pip uninstall community

then

> pip install python-louvain

then

> pip install networkx

in order to get my conda py37 environment to work correctly and to be able to call `community.best_partition()` without an attribute error.

I think, if you have `networkx` installed before `python-louvain`, it will claim the namespace for `community` and not allow you to run what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I use this solution:

```
import community.community_louvain as community_louvain

part = community_louvain.best_partition(G)
```

Reference: https://programmerclick.com/article/70941941990/

But here is another alternative:

> Figured out. Reinstalled, and reloaded, all works fine.
> Ps. for who does not know how to reload a module in jupyter:

```
from importlib import reload
reload(community)
```

Reference: https://github.com/taynaud/python-louvain/issues/48

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30565614)